# R dplyr column sort with alphanumeric characters

Tags: r, dplyr

Why does `dplyr` not sort the first column properly when it's composed of numeric and alphabetic characters?

```
> library(dplyr)
> y <- read.table("file.csv", sep = ",")
> arrange(y, V1)
   V1         V2         V3         V4         V5         V6
1   1 0.97348999 0.11047091 0.95841014 0.61826620 0.43164420
2  10 0.82178167 0.21619067 0.11993356 0.06335101 0.28703842
3  11 0.35952632 0.27595845 0.24760335 0.63887200 0.47491472
4  12 0.43775624 0.08852486 0.06870304 0.63670202 0.55432641
5  13 0.83894086 0.40484966 0.96735507 0.86764578 0.02588688
6  14 0.95258399 0.65029909 0.97183605 0.87688243 0.97729517
7  15 0.62839615 0.52999000 0.05722874 0.40709867 0.56039580
8   2 0.22754619 0.16812359 0.39432991 0.68562992 0.43066861
9   3 0.33318220 0.21108688 0.60911213 0.64475379 0.98617404
10  4 0.57208511 0.58709229 0.29435093 0.78603855 0.81185551
11  5 0.35548490 0.15229426 0.42423263 0.72963238 0.04401239
12  6 0.08575802 0.33310521 0.09671737 0.90820671 0.33289880
13  7 0.05743798 0.20439928 0.56411860 0.54859270 0.81053637
14  8 0.99056584 0.29960046 0.20765701 0.45722997 0.51354034
15  9 0.35839568 0.11667019 0.56498996 0.43971051 0.23968955
16  A 0.25645249 0.07045102 0.17046681 0.75700118 0.50269449
17  B 0.57722865 0.31544398 0.33129932 0.44173772 0.11600295
18  C 0.94242373 0.55745376 0.01542128 0.01723924 0.11413310
```

I'd like to see:

```
   V1         V2         V3         V4         V5         V6
1   1 0.97348999 0.11047091 0.95841014 0.61826620 0.43164420
2   2 0.22754619 0.16812359 0.39432991 0.68562992 0.43066861
3   3 0.33318220 0.21108688 0.60911213 0.64475379 0.98617404
4   4 0.57208511 0.58709229 0.29435093 0.78603855 0.81185551
5   5 0.35548490 0.15229426 0.42423263 0.72963238 0.04401239
6   6 0.08575802 0.33310521 0.09671737 0.90820671 0.33289880
7   7 0.05743798 0.20439928 0.56411860 0.54859270 0.81053637
8   8 0.99056584 0.29960046 0.20765701 0.45722997 0.51354034
9   9 0.35839568 0.11667019 0.56498996 0.43971051 0.23968955
10 10 0.82178167 0.21619067 0.11993356 0.06335101 0.28703842
11 11 0.35952632 0.27595845 0.24760335 0.63887200 0.47491472
12 12 0.43775624 0.08852486 0.06870304 0.63670202 0.55432641
13 13 0.83894086 0.40484966 0.96735507 0.86764578 0.02588688
14 14 0.95258399 0.65029909 0.97183605 0.87688243 0.97729517
15 15 0.62839615 0.52999000 0.05722874 0.40709867 0.56039580
16  A 0.25645249 0.07045102 0.17046681 0.75700118 0.50269449
17  B 0.57722865 0.31544398 0.33129932 0.44173772 0.11600295
18  C 0.94242373 0.55745376 0.01542128 0.01723924 0.11413310
```

Comment: @RichardScriven What I could do is edit/generalize my question to include any kind of library, not just `dplyr`.  I personally prefer `dplyr` but any answer using any library would work just fine, I think.

Comment: Along the same lines, how do you propose it accomplish the sort? If numeric, it sorts numerically, otherwise it sorts alphabetically. Unfortunately for you, `charToRaw("1") < charToRaw("A")`, which is the only other way it "knows" to order strings. If your input is hexadecimal, however, you might have other avenues.

Comment: @r2evans Maybe it'd be possible to sort the numbers first, then sort the letters next, voila?

Comment: How do the remainder of the alphabetic fields vary? That is, are they all 1-2 chars, or do they vary up to full words?

Comment: @r2evans They are just one character long.  I think in one case, there's a two character string.  But that's it.

Comment: Is this "sort all numbers before any letter"?

Comment: @r2evans Yes, that's correct.

Comment: In fact, just sorting the numbers would probably be enough, I don't really care much about the characters anyway...

Comment: If you want to filter out non-numeric values, how about `%>% filter(! grepl("[^0-9]", V1)) %>% mutate(V1 = as.numeric(V1)) %>% arrange(V1)`?

Comment: Well I want to keep non-numeric values in the list, but I don't really care how they're sorted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your disregard of alpha is a bit problematic, but how about:

```
library(dplyr)
arrange(y, as.numeric(V1))
# Warning in order(as.numeric(y$V1)) : NAs introduced by coercion
#    V1         V2         V3         V4         V5         V6
# 1   1 0.97348999 0.11047091 0.95841014 0.61826620 0.43164420
# 8   2 0.22754619 0.16812359 0.39432991 0.68562992 0.43066861
# 9   3 0.33318220 0.21108688 0.60911213 0.64475379 0.98617404
# 10  4 0.57208511 0.58709229 0.29435093 0.78603855 0.81185551
# 11  5 0.35548490 0.15229426 0.42423263 0.72963238 0.04401239
# 12  6 0.08575802 0.33310521 0.09671737 0.90820671 0.33289880
# 13  7 0.05743798 0.20439928 0.56411860 0.54859270 0.81053637
# 14  8 0.99056584 0.29960046 0.20765701 0.45722997 0.51354034
# 15  9 0.35839568 0.11667019 0.56498996 0.43971051 0.23968955
# 2  10 0.82178167 0.21619067 0.11993356 0.06335101 0.28703842
# 3  11 0.35952632 0.27595845 0.24760335 0.63887200 0.47491472
# 4  12 0.43775624 0.08852486 0.06870304 0.63670202 0.55432641
# 5  13 0.83894086 0.40484966 0.96735507 0.86764578 0.02588688
# 6  14 0.95258399 0.65029909 0.97183605 0.87688243 0.97729517
# 7  15 0.62839615 0.52999000 0.05722874 0.40709867 0.56039580
# 16  A 0.25645249 0.07045102 0.17046681 0.75700118 0.50269449
# 17  B 0.57722865 0.31544398 0.33129932 0.44173772 0.11600295
# 18  C 0.94242373 0.55745376 0.01542128 0.01723924 0.11413310
```

This also works with base:

```
y[ order(as.numeric(y$V1)), ]
```

**Edit**: OP then asked (deSpite! having said "*I don't really care*" ;-) how to then sort the non-numeric fields.

The reason the first command works is that the non-numeric fields are all converted to `NA`, which conveniently puts them *after* numbers in a sort. Well, both `dplyr::arrange` and `base::order` take arbitrary arguments, where ties in the first column are handled by the second argument, etc. So, in order to sort among the `NA`s (non-numeric `V1` elements), just add something that makes sense amongst them, such as ... "them":

```
arrange(y, as.numeric(V1), V1)
y[ order(as.numeric(y$V1), y$V1), ]
```

Comment: For clarity, because all non-"0-9" strings are converted to `NA`s, they are all dumped at the end of the data.frame, likely with their original order intact (but no other ordering guaranteed).

Comment: Yeah, I was a little surprised too. \*shrug\*

Comment: Now that `arrange(y, as.numeric(V1))` has been done to properly sort the integers, such that all non-"0-9" strings have been dumped at the end of the data frame, would it be possible to sort the characters next... ?  The pipe command comes to mind, for example, as a potential way to guarantee ordering of characters once the smoke clears.  I would appreciate it if you could expand your answer to include such usage cases :)

Comment: From your own comment: *but I don't really care how they're sorted*.

Comment: @r2evans Just got excited is all :))  Now I'm actually trying this code out and seeing that I would really benefit from the characters being sorted... who knew..

Comment: Try `arrange(y, as.numeric(V1), V1)`. (Funny, it really is that straight-forward ...) Equally, `y[ order(as.numeric(y$V1), y$V1), ]`.

Comment: `dplyr` solution looks more elegant, please consider expanding your answer, it looks great :))

Comment: Don't know if I'm getting over-excited here, but it seems like my question and this answer have collectively addressed a very important computer science sorting question... namely, how can you comfortably (and quickly) sort alphanumeric data using (pretty much) a beautiful one-liner.  I encourage people to upvote us!!

Comment: A more pedagogical discussion would venture into how "stable" the sort is as well; that is, given all sorting columns, if all are ties then does the original order (or non-sorted columns) prevail? In R, there are allegedly times when a stable sort is not guaranteed (see `?sort`, search for "stable"), in which case the "elegant one-liner" becomes the cause of hours of troubleshooting ... (not that I've ever been there ...)

Answer (score 3):

I recommend making V1 a factor and sorting the levels with a stringr package function before arranging:

```
> library(dplyr)
> library(stringr)

> y <- tibble(V1 = c("B", "A", 2, 1), V2 =c(1,2,3,4), V3=c(1,2,3,4))
> y %>%  
     dplyr::mutate(V1_fac = factor(V1, levels= str_sort(V1, numeric=TRUE))) %>%
     dplyr::arrange(V1_fac)
```

The numeric=TRUE option allows to sort V1 digits numerically, instead of as strings.
If some entries in V1 are not unique, you might want to use:

```
y %>%  
     dplyr::mutate(V1_fac = factor(V1, levels= str_sort(unique(V1), numeric=TRUE))) %>%
     dplyr::arrange(V1_fac)
```